# Does an Indian national need a visa to enter the Netherlands on a short business visit with a company invitation?

Tags: indian-citizens, netherlands, business-travel, schengen-visas

I am from India and need to go to the Netherlands for business. It's a short visit of 7 days and have a company invitation.

We referred to the official Dutch Immigration [information about business visits](https://ind.nl/en/short-stay/Pages/Business-visit.aspx) webpage.

**That webpage implies we can enter Amsterdam without visa, based on invitation from company abroad.** We have that invitation and also satisfy the other requirements in the checklist.

In this checklist, we are not sure about entry in Commercial Register Abroad. Please explain if anybody have gone through the same.

Can anybody share their experience if they have entered the Netherlands without visa based on Invitation?

Comment: @smci seems someone seriously messed up the texts for the website. The "without visa" section has the same text as the "with visa" section under "conditions", and identical for all countries, looks like.

Comment: @jwenting: Holy shit! That webpage could well cause people to be refused entry. What a screwup. You'd expect the Dutch to be more efficient.

Comment: @smci It looks to be (from the eyes of an IT professional) to be a quality assurance issue rather than a design flaw, someone didn't catch a serious flaw in the software.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you're a national of India, then you need a visa (or a residence permit) to enter the Schengen area. No exceptions.

The page you link to is quite confusing -- it shows both "with visa" and "without visa" options no matter which nationality you select in the dropdown. That seems to be a technical problem with the page, but it doesn't change the fact that **Indian citizens do require visas** for entering the Schengen area.

The complete list of nationalities requiring a visa is in [Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32001R0539)

Comment: The site works for me, but it is confusing.  When you select "Indian" the slider down the bottom moves to "With Visa" (although you can still select without).  When you set it to a country that does not require a visa (eg, Australia) then it changes to "Without visa"

Comment: Wow, that is one horribly counterintuitive UI.

Comment: Thanks all yes that UI made a lot of mess as wasn't sure do we need or do we not.. Thanks all for confirming it.

Comment: I just left them a mail through the contact page, feel free to add to the pressure ;-)